# elasticsearch.js: updateByQuery if exist otherwise insert

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch.js (node.js) SDK we could use `client.index({ ... })` to upsert a document (insert if not existed otherwise update).

However if I only want to update a specific field for example like this:

```
client.updateByQuery({
  index: 'test',
  body: {
    query: { match: { _id: '1' } },
    script: { inline: 'ctx._source.hello = "world"' }
  }
})
```

Now I want to create a document with id 1 if it doesn't exist with its field hello set to world or if document with id 1 exists then update its hello field to world. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [update API with doc as update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert). Use as below:

```
POST test/_update/1
{
  "doc":{
    "hello": "world"
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

Comment: Thx, if instead of using the REST api, how would I use the official elasticsearch node.js client/sdk to do this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/6.x/api-reference.html

Comment: Using this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/6.x/api-reference.html#_update